# Click on the customer and return your sales

Tags: django, django-filter

How do I click on the customer and return your sales?
That is, I want to click on the customer and that he filter that customer sales.

In fact I think I'm unable to think, because I thought the following:

- Customer link must be a value that when I click enters the sales page, only filtering sales.

Look what I tried, but without success.

[#models.py](https://github.com/rg3915/vendas/blob/master/vendas_project/vendas/models.py)

[#views.py](https://github.com/rg3915/vendas/blob/master/vendas_project/vendas/views.py)

```
class SaleList(ListView):
    template_name = 'sale_list.html'
    model = Sale
    context_object = 'sale_list'
    paginate_by = 20

...

    def get_queryset(self):
        s = Sale.objects.all()
        if self.request.GET.get('filter_sale', False):
            s = s.filter(customer='filter_sale')
        return s
```

[#customer_list.html](https://github.com/rg3915/vendas/blob/master/vendas_project/vendas/templates/customer_list.html)

```
...
{% for customer in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ customer.full_name }}</td>
...
```

[#sale_list.html](https://github.com/rg3915/vendas/blob/master/vendas_project/vendas/templates/sale_list.html)

@Daniel Roseman but now it does not return all sales when I click on sales, probably because of SaleList class is unique or because of urls.

```
url(r'^sale/$', SaleList.as_view(), name='sale_list'),
url(r'^sale/(?P<id>\d+)/$', SaleList.as_view(), name='sale_list'),
url(r'^sale/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', SaleDetailView.as_view(), name='sale_detail'),
```

Comment: Probably you should filter based on the value of 'filter_sale'. Try this: 's = s.filter(customer=self.request.GET.get('filter_sale')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly you need to define a URL for the sales list view that includes the ID of the customer whose details you want to see:

```
url(r'^sales/(?P<id>\d+)/$', SaleList.as_view(), name='sale_list'),
```

Then you need to provide a link in the customer list to that view:

```
{% for customer in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{% url 'sale_list' id=customer.id %}">{{ customer.full_name }}</a></td>
```

and then you need to filter by that ID in the queryset for the sales list view:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    s = Sale.objects.filter(customer=self.kwargs['id'])
    return s
```

Comment: but now it does not return all sales when I click on sales, probably because of SaleList class is unique or because of urls. I edited my question, see the final comment.

Comment: Resolved Thanks https://github.com/rg3915/vendas/commit/9a2223da3ff1829d796d0100f19be67c45dff626